# vscode find full version build number for jupyter extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have vscode version 1.56 installed for which I need to manually install the jupyter extension compatible (2021.5.1xxxxx).
Only recent versions are present in the marketplace and none is compatible.
I can simply tweek the download url (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/ms-toolsai/vsextensions/jupyter/2021.9.1001256920/vspackage) but I need to know the full build number and complete 2021.5.1xxxxx.

I can't find it in the github release page: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/releases/tag/2021.5.1

Cheers

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot update your vscode to match the recent jupyter?

Comment: it's because the vscode version is provided by my company. I can't install a newer version for the moment.

Comment: VScode is provided by my company as well but I can go to "Help" top left corner and then "Check for Updates" and it works. Sorry my intention is not to be aggressive, I would just find it extremely annoying every time vscode has a new version and a new thing breaks you know. I would suggest you make a ticket to the IT department to solve that issue for you :)

Comment: Yes but my VSCode is on a dev machine with no access to internet. Only access the intranet. Hence, it's not possible and I need to install packages manually. I know it's a pain :-(